# Swift: take a picture and upload to Parse; NSInternalConsistencyException

Tags: ios, swift

In my app, I have a button that opens a camera view. When I take a picture and "use picture", I save that image to a variable.
That `UIImage` is then being converted to `NSData` with `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` and sent to Parse as a `PFFile`.

Now, when I run the app on my actual device, when I press the upload to Parse button, I receive this error: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not save file data for buildingCam.jpg : (null)'`

This is my Swift code:

```
@IBAction func BuildingCamMainPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    var jpegImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)
    let file = PFFile(name: "buildingCam.jpg", data: jpegImage)

    file.save()

    var buildingCam = PFObject(className: "buildingCam")
    buildingCam["latitude"] = myLocation.last?.coordinate.latitude
    buildingCam["longitude"] = myLocation.last?.coordinate.longitude

    if(BuildingCamText.text.isEmpty){
        println("Geen tekst")
        BuildingCamText.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
        BuildingCamText.text = "Vul iets in"
    } else {
        BuildingCamText.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        buildingCam["description"] = BuildingCamText.text
    }
    buildingCam["file"] = file
    buildingCam.save()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you check what is being passed as sender?

The proper way to do this is to adopt `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`

```
 func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        let pickedImage:UIImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as UIImage
        let scaledImage = scaleImageWith(pickedImage)
        let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(scaledImage)
        let imageFile:PFFile = PFFile(data: imageData)
        PFUser.currentUser().setObject(imageFile, forKey: kParseClassNameProfileImage)
        PFUser.currentUser().saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (success: Bool, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if (success) {
                self.profileImageView.image = scaledImage
            } else {
                self.presentErrorMessage(error)
            }
        }

        picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
```

To answer the OP's request: 
Connect your button to the following and **make sure you also adopt UINavigationControllerDelegate**

```
func imagePicker(){
        var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
        imagePicker.delegate = self

        let returnIcon = UIBarButtonItem(image: kNavBarReturnIcon, style: .Plain, target: navigationController, action: "popViewControllerAnimated:")
        returnIcon.tintColor = kToolbarIconColor

        presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Alright, but how would I use that uploaded file in the Touch Up Inside action from my button?

Comment: let scaledImage = scaleImageWith(pickedImage) is a custom Function you can optionally implement to edit/crop all images to a Standard Size. *Highly Recommended

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant to say: how can I refer back to the PFFile from imagePickerController in my original button action?

Comment: That is a entirely separate question and task. I suggest you look online and give it a shot. If you have a specific issue, ask a different question. Thanks!

Comment: @ericgu what is the function that you used to scale the image down?